# Find the names contained in each sentence cycling through a large vector of names

Tags: r

This question is an extension of this one: [Find the names contained in each sentence (not the other way around)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44916792/find-the-names-contained-in-each-sentence-not-the-other-way-around/44916810)

I'll write the relevant part here. From this:

```
> sentences
[1] "Opposed as a reformer at Tübingen, he accepted a call to the University of Wittenberg by Martin Luther, recommended by his great-uncle Johann Reuchlin"
[2] " Melanchthon became professor of the Greek language in Wittenberg at the age of 21 with the help of Martin Luther"                                                                    
[3] " He studied the Scripture, especially of Paul, and Evangelical doctrine"
[4] " He was present at the disputation of Leipzig (1519) as a spectator, but participated by his comments."                                                                          
[5] " Johann Eck having attacked his views, Melanchthon replied based on the authority of Scripture in his Defensio contra Johannem Eckium"

toMatch <- c("Martin Luther", "Paul", "Melanchthon")
```

We obtained this result:

```
library(stringr)
lst <- str_extract_all(sentences, paste(toMatch, collapse="|"))
lst[lengths(lst)==0] <- NA
lst
#[[1]]
#[1] "Martin Luther"

#[[2]]
#[1] "Melanchthon"   "Martin Luther"

#[[3]]
#[1] "Paul"

#[[4]]
#[1] NA

#[[5]]
#[1] "Melanchthon"
```

But for a large `toMatch` vector, concatenating its values with the OR operator might not be very efficient. So my question is, how can be the same result be obtained using a function or a loop? Maybe this way it can be used a regular expression like `\<` or `\b` aroung the `toMatch` values so the system only looks for the whole words instead of strings.

I've tried this but don't know how to save the matches in `lst` to get the same result as above.

```
for(i in 1:length(sentences)){
    for(j in 1:length(toMatch)){
        lst<-str_extract_all(sentences[i], toMatch[j])
        }}
```

Comment: try this `lst[[i]][j] <- str_extract_all(sentences[i], toMatch[j])`

Comment: Try a nested `lapply` function. Not sure how well that compares to the `or` version, but it's certainly better than a nested loop:

`lapply(sentences,function(x) unlist(lapply(toMatch,function(y) str_extract_all(x,y))))`

Comment: @Val, what you propose *is* a nested loop ..

Comment: If you want to check each name individually, you have the upside of using a fixed regex pattern which is c.p. faster than a non-fixed pattern. But of course you have the downside of looping and running the regex multiple times. One option would be `lapply(toMatch, function(m) stringi::stri_extract_all_fixed(sentences, m, simplify = TRUE))`

Comment: @docendodiscimus maybe I should rephrase: it's certainly better than _this_ nested loop, meaning the one in the post.

Comment: @Prem it gives me an error `Error in `*tmp*`[[i]] : subindex out of limits` @Val the nested lapply works good but when trying with other (larger) data gives a weird error `Error in stri_extract_all_regex(string, pattern, simplify = simplify,  :   Incorrectly nested parentheses in regexp pattern.
 (U_REGEX_MISMATCHED_PAREN)` and, secondly, I'm not able to use regexp with `str_extract_all(x,y)`, this `str_extract_all(x,"\\<y\\>")` gives me a syntax error.

Answer (score 1):

Are you expecting something like this?

```
library(stringr)

sentences <- c(
"Opposed as a reformer at Tübingen, he accepted a call to the University of Wittenberg by Martin Luther, recommended by his great-uncle Johann Reuchlin",
" Melanchthon became professor of the Greek language in Wittenberg at the age of 21 with the help of Martin Luther",
" He studied the Scripture, especially of Paul, and Evangelical doctrine",
" He was present at the disputation of Leipzig (1519) as a spectator, but participated by his comments.",                                          
" Johann Eck having attacked his views, Melanchthon replied based on the authority of Scripture in his Defensio contra Johannem Eckium")

toMatch <- c("Martin Luther", "Paul", "Melanchthon")

for(i in 1:length(sentences)){
  lst[[i]] <- NA * seq(length(toMatch))
  for(j in 1:length(toMatch)){
    tmp = str_extract_all(sentences[i], toMatch[j])
    if (length(tmp[[1]]) > 0) {
      lst[[i]][j] <- tmp[[1]]
    }
  }}
lapply(lst, function(x) x[!is.na(x)])
lst
```